# Incrementally saving Clojure Data structures in a Git Repo

Tags: git, clojure

### Note:

This is tagged both Clojure and Git on purpose, as I'm happy to re-engineer on both the Clojure and the Git side of the software to make things work.

### Problem:

I have a bunch of clojure data structures. They average around 100 kb each when written out to disk (with pr). I have about 1000 of such files. These files are "structured" documents -- think of them as equivalent to SVG.

Now, I am making lots of small updates to each of these files (adding/deleting nodes, changing property on nodes). (then I (write (pr ...)) these files out.

Lastly, I'm storing all of these files in my git repo.

### Question:

I'm wondering if there is an efficient way to store these files (since different writes only have small modifications) -- i.e. if I have two copies of a single document in memory, it'd be 1MB + epsilon, not 2MB (since the two docs have only slight differences, and share most of the structure.)

I would like to somehow exploit this fact, and when it is being stored into git, have this similarity be taken advantage of.

### Possible considered solutions:

1) On the clojure side, instead of writing out an entire file, write only a "diff [consisting of assoc, dissoc] from the previous file." <-- This requires lots of engineering.

2) On the FS side, instead of storing individual files, throw the entire directory into bzip then commit it as a single *.bz2 (thus, similar files will ahve similar blocks). Down side is that stroing *.bz2 files in git does not seem like a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using [Datomic](http://www.datomic.com/) rather than Git?

What you are doing sounds like a roughly ideal use case for Datomic, which is essentially a Clojure-style database of "fact graphs" - which is pretty much exactly what your structured data look likes.

Datomic stores data in a manner very similar to Clojure's immutable data structures, i.e. it uses structural sharing to ensure that small changes only require a small amount of additional space. And it keeps the entire history in a manner similar to git - there's even a tool that simulates git repos in Datomic ([codeq](https://github.com/Datomic/codeq))

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting problem. Let's see what we can do.

Internally, Git saves in its database full copies of files you add to the repository. However, when you run `git gc` to optimise your local repository Git packs loose objects into packfiles. Similar files are stored in packfiles using delta compression. Quoting [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Packfiles):

> When Git packs objects, it looks for files that are named and sized similarly, and stores just the deltas from one version of the file to the next.

As a result storage of similar files in Git is optimised and the space usage is reduced.

Let's move from internals to the user interface part. From user's perspective Git is based on diffs. When you browse commits, merge patches and review changes you're dealing chiefly with diffs. Diffs are line-oriented. Hence, a minimal change in a single line causes both the old and the new version of the line to be stored as a whole in the generated diff. How we can make diffs between files you described easier to read? Make the lines shorter. I see two simple ways of achieving it.

Firstly, instead of saving Clojure data structures, convert them to [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=YAML&oldid=526510344#Examples). Files with data stored in YAML format have relatively short lines which solves the problem. [clj-yaml](https://github.com/lancepantz/clj-yaml) should come in handy.

If you insist on storing data as s-expressions, a second idea is to replace all spaces in generated files with newline characters. If readability counts, you can indent them afterwards. Before applying a simple regular expression replacing each space with `\n` check whether you have any strings with spaces inside.

Comment: Interesting, I knew that Git stored things as DAGs, but I didn't know Git stored different versions as Diffs (though it's obvious in retrospect). This is very clever. So the ideal situation is to map it so that changes in clojure structure maps to changes in lines, which diff then picks up on.

Comment: @user1647794, exactly. This should render the diffs minimal and as a result reduce the size of each commit.

Comment: as a matter of fact, Git is not based on diffs.

Comment: @LaurentPetit, thanks for your comment. I've revised the answer and clarified the oversimplifications I had made. Do you find this version accurate?